# How can I use setters with a JList with a custom renderer to set a cell's contents?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, setter, listcellrenderer

I have a JList of player objects, i.e. `JList<Player>`, which uses an implementation of `ListCellRenderer<Player>` as its cell renderer. The cell renderer itself is a JPanel and contains JLabels displaying information about the player. However, I would like to also display information separate to the player that I can edit with a setter.

In the code below, I have written a minimal example of my code. I know I can edit and update information related to the object the list holds, which I have included as a button. However, say I have an additional entry in the JList cell, "Winnings". I want to write a setter for this JLabel, but I have no idea how to do so, or if this is even possible. What is the best way to do this if it is possible?

For what it's worth, this is for a university-related project, and I cannot edit the player object's implementation to include this information.

```java
public class Example {

    JList<Player> list;
    DefaultListModel<Player> model;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        list = new JList<>(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new Renderer());

        Player player = new Player("Harry", 5);
        model.addElement(player);

        JButton setNameButton = new JButton("Set player name to Ron");
        setNameButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            player.setName("Ron");
            list.revalidate();
            list.repaint();
        });

        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(setNameButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Player {
        String name;
        int points;

        public Player(String name, int points) {
            this.name = name;
            this.points = points;
        }

        public int getPoints() { return points; }
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }

    public class Renderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Player>
    {
        private JLabel playerName = new JLabel("");
        private JLabel points = new JLabel("");
        private JLabel winnings = new JLabel("Winnings: ");

        public Renderer()
        {
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            add(playerName);
            add(points);
            add(winnings);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Player> list, Player player, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            playerName.setText("Name: " + player.getName());
            points.setText("Points: " + Integer.toString(player.getPoints()));

            return this;        
        }

        public void setWinnings(String string) {
            // I want to be able to write a setter for winnings, i.e.
            // winnings.setText("New winnings: " string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *For what it's worth, this is for a university-related project, and I cannot edit the player object's implementation to include this information.* - makes no sense. The "winnings" is a property of a Player. A "renderer" is shared by all Players in the JList, so it can't be used to contain the winnings for a given Player. Maybe "winnings" is supposed to be a calculated value based on the Points the Player has accumulated?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your note about how renderers worked was what I needed to answer my overall question. I cannot edit the player object to violate the interface it implements since the assignment is meant to teach us how to work with legacy model implementations that you cannot touch. I asked this question in a few places and one answer I got which I have now implemented successfully to solve my issue was to just wrap the Player in another object that contains a Player and the winnings, and so changes to that object are reflected in the cell.